# Make toggle button stick to each other

Tags: android, xml, layout, toggle

How can I make the `toggle button` stick to each other by remove the space between `toggleSun` and `toggleMon`?

I add

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/toggleSun"
android:layout_toEndOf="@id/toggleSun"
```

in `toggleMon` element, but the space still there.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New ToggleButton"
        android:checked="false"
        android:id="@+id/toggleMon" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New ToggleButton"
        android:id="@+id/toggleSun"
        android:checked="false" />
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Anyone ?

Comment: Use a RelativeLayout

Comment: @MuratK. After I change to Relative, I only see one toggle button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add :  android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New ToggleButton"
    android:checked="false"
    android:id="@+id/toggleMon" />

<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New ToggleButton"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
    android:id="@+id/toggleSun"
    android:checked="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Making it the main view as RelativeLayout will make both the ToggleButtons overlap each other.. So use the attribute android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toggleMon" on the lower ToggleButton.
That way both the ToggleButton will be visible